# Guarantee of order of conditions in if statement?

Tags: java

Given that example code:

```
boolean foo(String arg)
{
    if( arg != null && arg.equalsIgnoreCase("bar") )
        //Do something
}
```

Do I have guarantee that `equalsIgnoreCase()` is only called if `arg` is not `null` ?

Comment: Other than Java specifications?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what `&&` was designed for (in C).  Similarly `||`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Java does offer short-cicuiting for conditionals, operating from left to right.

[JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.
>
> ---
>
> If the resulting value is `false`, the value of the conditional-and expression is `false` and the right-hand operand expression *is not evaluated*.
>
> If the value of the left-hand operand is true, then the right-hand expression is evaluated; if the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8). The resulting value becomes the value of the conditional-and expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java will guarantee that `equalsIgnoreCase` is only called if `arg` is not null.  It will evaluate its operands from left to right, and in the case of `&&` (and `||`), it will not evaluate the right operand if it doesn't need to evaluate it.

[Section 15.23 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) states:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

and

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is false, the value of the conditional-and expression is false and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated.